# Problems installing miniconda

Tags: python, anaconda, source

I'm trying to install Miniconda in a Linux server. I don't have root/sudo access, so I'm using these steps:

1. Download the Miniconda installer:

   ```
   wget https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
   ```
2. Run the intaller:

   ```
   sh Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
   ```
3. Open `.bash_profile` with `vim`:

   ```
   vim .bash_profile
   ```
4. Add the following to `.bash_profile`:

   ```
   export PATH=$HOME/miniconda3/bin:$PATH
   ```
5. Save and close `vim`: Hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> and then type `:wq`.
6. Run:

   ```
   source .bash_profile
   ```

When I write step 6, I'm having this error message:

```
-sh: 17: source: not found
```

I really need Miniconda to run my project. Can someone help me?

Comment: What OS & release are you using?

Comment: `lsb-release -a` will list some details (-a says to list all)

Comment: @guiverc Ubuntu 16.04.6

Comment: It looks like you are using the POSIX `/bin/sh` shell, whereas the instructions assume `bash`. Try switching to a bash shell (by typing `bash`).

Comment: Can you explain it a bit more @steeldriver ?

Comment: Well the `source` command is a bash synonym for the POSIX `sh` command `.` so you *could* try `. .bash_profile` however it is probably safer to switch to bash if that's the shell for which the instructions are intended. You may wish to set your login shell to bash using `chsh` ex. `chsh -s /bin/bash`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to write `export "PATH=/HOME/your_user/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"` directly in the terminal.

The only problem is that we will have to export miniconda every time we enter the system, but it works normally.